# Sharepoint Rest Api error RefinementFilters

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I need to filter data from a search, but when passing a string to the refinementfilter an error occurs.

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException

When I pass the parameters without the space character, for example, the query returns the results normally. However, when I pass the parameter with the space character the error occurs

My request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"JSON",
        url: url + "/_api/search/query?querytext='teste'&startrow=0&rowlimit=100&selectproperties='Url,Title,Filename,AreaAtuacao,tipoConteudo,Created,ContentType'&sourceid='e1327b9c-2b8c-4b23-99c9-3730cb29c3f7'&refinementfilters='and(SPContentType:equals('Publicação'),AreaAtuacao:('Institucional'),TipoConteudo:('Artigos'))'",
            headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
        },
            success: function (dados) {
                console.log(dados);
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to URL encode your string in order to use it in your AJAX request. To encode the value in JavaScript, you can use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: give me a example?